# Only Returns One Object In Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
if (lastUserMessage === '/love') {
    const love = [];
    newlove = prompt("What do you love?", "Thing you love.");
    love.push(newlove);
    localStorage.setItem('love', JSON.stringify(love));
    botMessage = 'Awesome.';
}

if (lastUserMessage === 'What do I. love?') {
    var love2 =   JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("love"));
    botMessage = love2;
}
```

Its suppose to store more than 1 object in the array, but I only get 1 value back.

Comment: This is not valid JavaScript, you can't have a newline in a string.

Comment: Where do you store more than one element in the array? `const love = []` creates an empty array, then you do `love.push(newlove)`. That's only one element.

Comment: You shouldn't do `const love = []` every time you run this code. Do it once at the beginning of the script.

Comment: I did that and still only get one value. How do I add on and not just write over the current object.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you always initialize your value to an empty array:

```
const love = [];
```

But it sounds like you expect it to retain the previously stored values in local storage.  To do that, just initialize it to those values:

```
const love = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('love'));
```

As an extra step you might also do a `null` check on the stored array, just in case this is the first time the code was run and nothing is stored yet.  Untested, but I suspect something like this may work:

```
const love = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('love') || '[]');
```

The idea being that `getItem` will return `null` if the item doesn't exist, so in that case you'd pass `'[]'` to `JSON.parse` and start with an empty array.

Comment: Thank you david! That worked like a charm :)